# decltype(auto) return type and lifetime issues

Tags: c++, object-lifetime, decltype-auto

I am just looking at some code with the following rough outline.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename F>
decltype(auto) do_something(T&& object, F f) {
    return f(std::forward<T>(object));
}

struct object {
    int x;
    int& ref() { return x; }
    int const& ref() const { return x; } 
};

struct f {
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) operator()(T&& x) {
   return x.ref();
}
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    auto & x = do_something(object{}, f{});

    return 0;
}
```

so if i called like this

```
auto& do_something(object{}, f{);
```

Some questions around this are that if `f` returns a reference and `f` takes ownership of `object` via move semantics are we not left with a lifetime issue?

What are the potential issues of returning by `decltype(auto)`?

Or is this better

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct object {
    int x{};
    
    int const& ref() const noexcept { return x; }
    int& ref() noexcept { return x; }
};

struct functor {
    
    template<typename T>
    decltype(auto) operator()(T&& arg) {
        return arg.ref();
    }
};

template<typename T, typename F>
decltype(auto) apply(T&& o, F f) {
    if constexpr(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>) {
        return f(std::forward<T>(o)); 
    }else {
        auto result = f(std::forward<T>(o));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fair point. Lets say it returns a reference to some part of object.

Comment: If `f` is moving `object` into a locally defined variable (automatic storage duration) and you're returning `object` by reference from `f` then you have a dangling reference.

Comment: In your latest edit, `f` doesn't take ownership of its argument, so it's not an issue.

Comment: but at the end of the expression object is destroyed and you returned a reference to part of it.

Comment: In C++, the lifetime extension via reference is not transitive.

Comment: So returning using decltype(auto) is dangerous then. as you can end up with what I am trying to ask

Comment: @BlairDavidson *"at the end of the expression object is destroyed"* That's not the problem of the person writing `do_something`. `f`, if called directly, has the same issue.

Comment: fair point. Would a better alternative be to check iff T is a reference and then return a decayed and non decayed in a constexpr if statement.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct object {
    int x{};
    
    int const& ref() const noexcept { return x; }
    int& ref() noexcept { return x; }
};

struct functor {
    
    template<typename T>
    decltype(auto) operator()(T&& arg) {
        return arg.ref();
    }
};

template<typename T, typename F>
decltype(auto) apply(T&& o, F f) {
    if constexpr(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>) {
        return f(std::forward<T>(o)); 
    }else {
        auto result = f(std::forward<T>(o));
        return result;
    }
}

Comment: If you're just writing the wrapper (`do_something`), it's not your problem to solve. The wrapper is fine, except the minor issue I outlined in the answer. There are still valid usecases for the current version (you can use the reference in this very expression, before it dangles).

Comment: You'd probably want `auto const result = std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<T>(o));` for `apply`, so the `auto& x = apply(object{}, f{});` would be a `const` for `x`.  Checked with `std::cout << (std::is_const_v<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(x)>::type> ? "const" : "mutable") << "\n";`.

Answer (score 1):

> `f` takes ownership of object via move semantics

If `f` is a function, then it's not possible for it to return a valid reference to it in the first place, even without your wrapper.

But your code doesn't take ownership of the object it's given, so it's fine.

---

There's a different, rather obscure failure scenario: `f` is a functor that moves the parameter into its member variable, then returns a reference to it. Then you'd get a dangling reference after `f` dies:

```
struct A
{
    object x;
    object &operator()(object y)
    {
        x = std::move(y);
        return x;
    }
};
```

Here, `A{}(object{}).foo()` is legal, but `do_something(object{}, A{}).foo()` is UB.

The solution is to use `F &&f` (which is a good idea anyway, to avoid a copy). You should also `std::forward<F>(f)` when calling it:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
decltype(auto) do_something(T &&object, F &&f)
{
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<T>(object));
}
```

Comment: Im not sure how this make much of a difference. If I pass in an lvalue to do_something then perfectly forwarding to f is ok and the refrence returned for f is still valid as object is still alive.

Comment: Can you explain further with a code snippet. Keen to get your understanding.

Comment: @BlairDavidson If you pass an lvalue argument to `do_something`, it does not prevent `f` from updating this argument (such as moving from it).

Comment: thats true but lets say the f(...) call takes a forwarding_reference then it should be ok.

Comment: lets say f is defined as somereftype& f(T&& input)

Comment: @BlairDavidson There are many "lets say..."s. You should update the question itself to provide this additional information, otherwise it is too generic to be answered. Why don't you provide some example use case?

Comment: Does this give you a bit of a better idea about what I mean?